# i only output integer but string dont outputing

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Hello guys i am doing wizard but last activity there is not printing name (String) whats the problem can someone solve it this is xml code of last activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".thirdActivity3">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"


        android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:text="lala"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:text="lala"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"


        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```
class thirdActivity3 : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var textView: TextView
    private lateinit var textView2: TextView


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_third3)


        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView)
        textView2 = findViewById(R.id.textView2)

        val extras = intent.extras

        if(extras != null){
            textView.text = extras.getString("NAME","") //getString("NAME","")
            textView2.text = extras.getInt("AGE",0).toString() //getInt("AGE",0).toString()




        }
    }
}
```

and this is activityy codee when i am running age is printing but somehow name string not printing

this is mainActivity where i am transfering name data to second activity with startactivity(intent)

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var editTextName:EditText
    private lateinit var nextButton: Button

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        editTextName=findViewById(R.id.editTextName)
        nextButton=findViewById(R.id.nextButton)

        nextButton.setOnClickListener {

            val name = editTextName.text.toString()
            val intent = Intent(this,secondActivity2::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("PERONS_NAME",name)

            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

```
class secondActivity2 : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var inputTextAge:EditText
    private lateinit var finishButton: Button

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second2)
        inputTextAge=findViewById(R.id.inputTextAge)
        finishButton=findViewById(R.id.finishButton)


        val extras = intent.extras
        var name = ""
        if (extras != null){
            name=extras.getString("PERSON_NAME","")



        }


        finishButton.setOnClickListener {

            val age = inputTextAge.text.toString().toInt()
            val intent = Intent(this,thirdActivity3::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("NAME",name)

            intent.putExtra("AGE",age)




            startActivity(intent)



        }
    }
}
```

and this last one is second activity where i am outputing name and transfering to last page thirdactivity. first page code is third activity and problem is that i can read age in activity but name not ouputing

Comment: where you send name? can you post that code

Comment: yes i updated code can you see

Comment: Look at your MainActivity. you have a spelling error intent.putExtra("PERONS_NAME",name)

Answer (score 0):

In **MainActivity**, the **KeyName** in intent is `PERONS_NAME` whereas in
**SecondActivity2**, the **KeyName** is `PERSONS_NAME`.

Clearly there is a mismatch of **KeyNames**.

In order to solve the issue, make sure  the **KeyName** in **MainActivity** and **SecondActivity2** are same.